# XSL-FO Number Formatting

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, number-formatting

Currently, I am trying to format numbers using XSL using the below format.

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number($number, "#,##0.00")' />
```

However I am facing an unusual issue, For numbers less than 4 digits, if the XML input is 745.15, the output will be correctly shown as 745.15. However if the XML input is 845, the output will be 845 itself not the required 845.00

These are some of the other solutions which I have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(format-number($fv15, '#,##0.00'), '.00'), '.00')" >
<xsl:value-of select="xdoxslt:ms_format_number($_XDOXSLTCTX, $fv15, '#,##0.00')"/>
```

Comment: What processor are you using? Works fine for me in Xalan, Saxon 6.5.5 and Saxon 9.5 (HE/PE/EE).

Comment: Shouldn't '#,##0.00' be '#,##.00' ?

Comment: @Rnet - No, that would create strings like `8,45.00`. I'd actually do it like `#,###.00` so something like `.25` didn't come out like `0.25`.